# How to keep a session going with .net ssh sshclient

Tags: c#, ssh

```
SshClient client;
var sethost = client.RunCommand("export DOCKER_HOST=:2375");
var infohost = client.RunCommand("docker info");
var ps = client.RunCommand("docker ps");
```

I am using the above commands with ssh client for .Net but it does not keep the state from the first command that does an export in the next two commands.

If I ssh in manually and do the 3 commands it works as I expects, but above c# code seem to forget about the export in the followup commands.

Comment: If that are your only three commands can't you && them, like so: `export DOCKER_HOST=:2375 && docker info && docker ps` so you only have to make one call to `RunCommand`

Comment: more commands will be added that that also depends on the export had been run. i just dont understand if the run command is like opening a new bash every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using the [SSH.NET](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/) library. In the following solution I used the [stable version (2013.4.7)](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/104648) which is also available as NuGet package.

There are two possible solutions to get this to work. The first one is to combine the commands you want to run in one single RunCommand. A RunCommand starts a new shell each time its invoked and with that it forgets any environment settings you have executed. By chaining the commands with the [`&& or ||`](https://superuser.com/questions/235761/how-do-i-chain-commands-on-the-console) operator you achieve that all commands can be executed in the same Shell.

```
static void SolutionOne(ConnectionInfo connection)
{
    using (SshClient client = new SshClient(connection))
    {
        client.ErrorOccurred += (e, s) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(s.Exception);
        };

        client.Connect();

        // each RunCommand starts its own/new Shell...
        var sethost = client.RunCommand("export DOCKER_HOST=:2375");
        // ... nothing is kept...
        var infohost = client.RunCommand("export -p");
        if (!infohost.Result.Contains("DOCKER_HOST"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("sorry, a new shell was started for this command");
        }
        // ... across run commands
        var ps = client.RunCommand("echo has value: $DOCKER");
        Console.WriteLine(ps.Result);

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Chain the linux commands...");
        // chain all commands with &&
        var concatAll = client.RunCommand("export DOCKER_HOST=:2375 && export -p | grep DO && echo has value: $DOCKER_HOST");
        // you should see DOCKER_HOST on the last line!
        Console.WriteLine("> see has value: 2375 at the end?");
        Console.WriteLine(concatAll.Result);
    }
}
```

The second solution is to obtain a `ShellStream` from the `SshClient`. That gives you the opportunity to read and write bytes very much similar like you would do a file.
After we have a connection and stream established we Read everything there is to read. Once the stream is empty we send our first command by Writing to the stream. Then we wait a bit for the stream to get data to read and then proceed in reading from the stream again until the stream is empty. That is when we can start the next command, rinse and repeat until all commands are done.

```
static void SolutionTwo(ConnectionInfo connection)
{
    using (SshClient client = new SshClient(connection))
    {
        client.ErrorOccurred += (e, s) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(s.Exception);
        };

        client.Connect();

        using (var stream = client.CreateShellStream("dumb", 512, 96, 800, 600, 8191))
        {
            stream.ErrorOccurred += (e, s) =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(s.Exception);
            };
            // read welcome message
            Console.WriteLine(ReadFromStream(stream));

            // first command and read its output
            WriteToStream(stream, "uname\n");
            Console.WriteLine(ReadFromStream(stream));

            // second and output
            WriteToStream(stream, "df\n");
            Console.WriteLine(ReadFromStream(stream));

            // third and output
            WriteToStream(stream, "ps aux\n");
            Console.WriteLine(ReadFromStream(stream));
        }
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine(" >>>>>we are all done");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    }
}



static void WriteToStream(ShellStream stream, string command) 
{
    stream.Write(command);
}

static StringBuilder ReadFromStream(ShellStream stream)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    // there seems to be a timing/concurrency issue
    // which I only could fix with using this 
    // useless Sleep calls
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    // wait for the Stream to have data
    while (stream.Length == 0)
    {
        // yes, I know ...
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
    // let's read!
    string line;
    while ((line = stream.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        result.AppendLine(line);
    }
    return result;
}
```

As you noticed in `ReadFromStream` method there is some dubious hacking. I had a huge struggle to read reliable from the stream. In my initial attempts I used the `DataReceived` event but no matter how I tried it either did work for a few lines or even chars or it didn't work at all. In the end I fell back to a nasty Thread.Sleep call that worked reliable all the time. Maybe it is a bug in the library or something in my local setup but I gave up.